# Is it possible to replace stock 'Phone' app?

Tags: applications

First of all, I know one can replace the dialer app and there are many options available for it. 
But is it possible to replace the stock phone app? Is there any calling app that uses the normal cellular network to make calls apart from the stock android app?

The reason why I am asking this is because I am having problems with talking on handset on my Nexus 5 since I update to Lollipop. And I figured that if I replace the phone app, this problem could be solved as my calls on Skype and Hangout are normal which proves that the microphone is fine and the problem lies in the software.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier on a custom ROM, as you can flash what you want. However, since you're on Stock, here's what I'll suggest.

Disable (uninstall) your phone app (if that's possible), then install another phone app of your choice. Automatically, that'll take over as your default phone app.

Answer (score 0):

Something:
There is no need to replace it. Just try Google Phone temporary and set it as default phone app. Also that mught be microphone issue. Nexus 5 has 2 microphones. One at the bottom used by Cell and second at the top used by applications. Skype and Hangout uses top one.

Solution:
To test your microphone, call someone. If they dont hear you, set your sound to speaker. That will switch to the top micro. If that worked... Well oops your bottom microphone is dead :/